# DateTime.toString shows with time when output to Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Edit: I figured it out, ill explain here.

I had the following code filled in
I didn't want the time part, just the year, day and month

```
  //model
public DateTime Indate { get; set; } //this is filled in by a form with "01/01/2015"

 //controller
(DateTime)person.Indate).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

What i Failed to notice is that this only applied for that line code, i missed out on adding that line EVERYWHERE.

```
htmlBody1 += "<tr><td style=\"width: 225px\">Starting Date Project </td><td>:&nbsp;" + person.Indate + "</td></tr>";
```

This was my incorrect line, i forgot to add the .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") there aswell

I solved it.

thanks to Damien_The_Unbeliever, for pointing out that it does not remember your format if you output it sometimes. this made me realise i had to specficly point out out everywhere.

Comment: That format string *will* only show the date, so your sample code is missing where the problem actually comes in. I suspect your custom formatting is not being used, and default formatting is occurring in the view. Your edit shows a public `DateTime` property without any data annotations, if you are using that directly in a Razor view, it will likely be formatted in a default manner based on user locale, so your custom formatting will be missed. Also, a `DateTime` has no concept of "format", format is only in the visual representation of a `DateTime`, not part of its value.

Comment: Use `dt.ToString("d")` or  `dt.ToShortDateString` or  `dt.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM")`

Comment: Your code should be working.. so thats weird

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: so user should not use format they need, but must use some another format?

Comment: I added the person model, does that help?

Comment: @zerkms: why? OP states that he wants: _" year, day and month"_, so `yyyy-dd-MM`. Also, `dd-MNM-yyy` is not a valid format string either.

Comment: I suspect what you've not shown is that you're then converting back to a `DateTime` and you're (somehow) expecting that object to "remember" that it was only constructed from a date string (and possibly even which format it came from). That's *not* how it works. A `DateTime` stores an internal, numerical representation of dates and doesn't remember *any* formatting information.

Comment: @user3712713 I would really suggest you to add a full running example that demonstrates it. Otherwise it's hard for people to help you

Comment: @zerkms: also, if he'd use `DateTime.ToShortDateString` he would have noticed that it's not a `DateTime` but a `String`.

Comment: I think @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right,
I just noticed, whenever i store it into a PDF it works correctly, but if i pass it as html into an email, it forgets the format and simply reverts back to adding 00:00:00

Comment: @user3712713 The edit you just added does not help. Show code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran this code and it outputs exactly what you you want:

[image: DateTime Format String]

You can also use [`ToString("d")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#ShortDate), which will output `28.10.2014` (based on your culture), or [`ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx), which will output the same.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a parenthesis in the code shown. Your formatting statement isn't valid C# code.

With that saud, this works for me:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
System.Console.WriteLine(((DateTime)date).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```